# How to find from which file $block->getContent() called?

Tags: magento2.4.1, magento-2-commerce

I am using Magefan blog extension,

app\code\Magefan\Blog\view\frontend\templates\post\view.phtml

```
        <div class="post-text-hld">
            <?= /*@noEscape*/ $block->getContent() ?>
            <div class="clear clearfix"></div>
        </div>
```

From which file content gets called?

Answer (score 0):

You can check related block class that used for view.phtml
I believe its located on **app\code\Magefan\Blog\Block\Post\View.php**

The getContent is came from Post Model which is located : **app\code\Magefan\Blog\Model\Post.php**

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Block folder inside your Magefan module, if there is any file open it and see inside public execute funtion

```
public function execute(){
  //from here your block content is call
}
```

from here your block content is called